# Stripping HTML tags in Moodle - TinyMCE

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce, moodle

When I am writing on TinyMCE in Moodle's wiki and writing an html code like this:

```
<a onclick="testFunction()" rel="test">myTest</a>
```

the onclick, rel and all other attributes from the anchor tag are getting stripped. However when I am writting the same code in the TinyMCE editor in the Moodle's forum, then it does not strip the anchor tag.

I have granted both the Allow EMBED and OBJECT tags and Enable trusted content and also did that for every user. Does anyone have any clue about this issue?

How to disable HTML tags stripping in Moodle's WiKi or at least allow a predefined set of tags?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to find the tinymce configuration in moodle installation (it is usually a file called `tinymce.js.php`) and change the settings [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) according to your needs (check the links to get to know how to define valid attributes in order to keep them in the editor).

Comment: in the lib.php document, for the tinyMce editor the only line that is related to valid_elements is this:
`$params['valid_elements'] = 'script[src|type],*[*]';`

As you can see the `*,[*]` indicates that all elements are valid.

Comment: you are using which version of tinymce? as far as i can remember there was a bug with this setting set to * - leading to the problem you describe

Comment: I am using `Moodle 2.2.1 (Build: 20120109)` and `TinyMce's 3.4.6`

Comment: you could try an update to the latest tinymce version 3.5.2 (an update can be easily done)

Comment: I will try to update it, but there is a part that I still don't understand. How is it possible the tinyMce editor inside the forum to not strip the tag but the WIKI's editor to strip it? That means the valid_elements have been set correctly
They are using the same tinyMce editor..

Comment: that is an issue i do not understand myself, except they have different configurations